# NullPointerException when calling method from another fragment in activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm very disappointed.

In my activity where i also start the fragment, i have a fragment view, and i call the method from another fragment by using the findFragmentById and then the fragmentview id.

onCreate in my activity:

```
        frgmntView = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frgmntView);

        mFrgmntManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        gmm = (GlobalMultiMenu) mFrgmntManager.findFragmentById(R.id.frgmntView);

        startMenu();
```

And another void where i call the method:

```
public void startMenu() {
            mFrgmntTransaction = mFrgmntManager.beginTransaction();
            mFrgmntTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
            mFrgmntTransaction.replace(R.id.frgmntView, new GlobalMultiMenu()).commit();
            actualFrgmnt = 0;

            gmm.updateBottomItems();

            isDoingTurn = false;
        }
```

But this returns null pointer, please help.
Thanks

Comment: man, it isnt, i was searching for answer about 30 min and i didnt find the answer yet

Answer (score 0):

make that Method `Static`

And call it.

Example :

`FragmentName.MethodName();`

Comment: no, this is not the solution...also i knew about this, but i cannot make that void static

Comment: where is your updateBottomItems(); define ?? In Activity or Fragment ?

Comment: in fragment and im editing some edittext in update method